# Есть популярная библиотека на gitHub, а где инструкции, мануалы к ней?

Tags: android, github

Вот библиотека [тут](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop), а где написано как её использовать?

Нужно в библиотеке "android-crop" установить прямоугольник для выделения (rectangle)

Comment: Не беглый взгляд показал там наличие пример и еще маленький tutorial...

Comment: вроде бы, прямо по ссылке и написано. по английски. начиная со слова usage. // у вас не отображается? тогда попробуйте склонировать этот репозиторий и прочитать файл `readme.md`

Comment: Этого очень мало. Мне к примеру надо не квадрат выделять а прямоугольник и где написано как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по [исходнику](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/soundcloud/android/crop/Crop.java#L46) соотношение сторон задается методом `withAspect(dX, dY)`.

Отдельный метод `asSquare()` просто устанавливает оба значения равным 1.

Мануалы,разжевывающие все аспекты использования библиотеки вам никто не обязан писать, тем более для такой простой библиотеки, как та, что вас интересует.

Не хватает информации - есть исходники. Смотрите, изучайте ... там есть комментарии и пояснения к методам. Естественно и все возможные для библиотеки методы оттуда узнать можно очень легко.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Минимальный функционал, а в данном случае весь смысл библиотеки, приведен в описании. Мануалы никто делать не обязан. За пределами гитхаба не увидел популярности абсолютно.